# How to make an image appear on click, exactly where the click occurred?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, pug

I am trying to add an image when an area of a canvas is clicked. I would prefer to use jquery but vanilla js or css is fine. 
The problem is, I can add a click function using click and append, however it does not appear in the exact place i clicked, and this is what i want to happen. 
also i am trying to add a touch event to the click event, and I get the error "expected one argument but got two"

(I am using a typescript / scss / pug preprocessor, gulp compiler)

i tried to randomize the x and y coordinates, however this just randomized them and didn't "bind" them to my click event. i also did attempt this with css using the :Active ~ selector, however it did not appear where the user was active, only at the top left of the container it's in. so i don't know if CSS is the way to go.

```
$("#clickimage").click(function(){
$('<img src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300">').appendTo($("#clickimage"));
        });

$('#clickimage').ontouchstart = ();
```

css looks like:

```
#clickimage {
    display: none;
}
```

attempted css:

```
:active ~ #clickimage{
    display: block;
  }
```

html

```
<canvas width="632" height="418" id="clickimage"></canvas>
```

Comment: where is the html file where u append the image to the id `clickimage`?

Comment: ```<canvas width="632" height="418"  id="clickimage"></canvas>```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this in vanilla JS will help you - the trick is using position fixed with offsetX/Y.

```js
function paintImage(e){
  document.querySelector('#wrapper').innerHTML += `<img src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300" style="left:${e.offsetX}px;top:${e.offsetY}px">`;
 }
document.addEventListener('click', paintImage);
```

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```